# If/Else Is not Working in my scnario? PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

Hi This is my HTML Code

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="next.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="click">
</form>
<body>
<html>
```

And this is my PHP file

```
<?php
$i="123";
if($i=="123")
{   
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents("http://www.lucchesesdeli.com/Social%20Media%20logos.png");
}
else
{   
echo "same page";   
}
?>
```

I am trying to Display Some page if the User Input is `123` if its not One `123` I want to Display some other data like `same page`

So here In If I have used `if($i=="123")` but if the input is anything Its going for If ... So I changed to `if($i="123")` ... but its going for `Same Page`

Can you suggest me what I am missing...

Comment: Hi DownVoter....Mention Comment before down vote ....

Comment: so what are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$i=$_POST['text'];
if($i==123)
{   
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo 'hello';
}
else
{   
echo "bye";   
}
?>
```

check if it works, if yes then you are making a mistake in file_get_contents